# How to make a manually created button invisible after it is clicked in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, button, invisible

I manually created a button using the code below. Usually with buttons I can set their `Visible=false` to make them invisible, which I do in the `setInvisible` method I call when the button is clicked. I can't seem to do this with my manually created button, though?

```
myButtonObject start = new myButtonObject();

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    EventHandler myHandler = new EventHandler(start_Click);
    start.Click += myHandler;
    start.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 500);
    start.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(101, 101);
    //start.Text="Start";
    this.Controls.Add(start);
}

void start_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    start.Visible=false;
    setInvisible(); // sets a group of buttons invisible
    setVisible();   // sets another group visible 
}


public class myButtonObject : UserControl
{
    // Draw the new button. 
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        // Draw the button in the form of a circle
        graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Goldenrod, 0, 0, 100, 100);        
        graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, "Start", new Font("Arial Black", 12.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), new Point(23,37), SystemColors.ControlText);
        myPen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show us the code in setInvisible().

Comment: all it does is set other buttons in the class to invisible, like this

button1.Visible=false;

Comment: Try to call: button1.Hide();

Comment: i can't seem to access the "start" button object?

Comment: should i create it outside the constructor?

Comment: Works!!! edited my code :)

all i had to do was move the start object outside the constructor so that i could access it in the handler method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare your manual created button as a *field*, outside the *constructor*:

```
private myButtonObject start;
```

Something like that

```
public class MainForm()
{
    // Declare the button as a field in order to have access to it
    // in any property/method/constructor within the class
    private myButtonObject start;

    ...
}

public MainForm() 
{
    InitializeComponent();

    start = new myButtonObject();
    EventHandler myHandler = new EventHandler(start_Click);
    start.Click += myHandler;
    start.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 500);
    start.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(101, 101);
    this.Controls.Add(start);

    ...
} 

private void setInvisible() 
{
    ...
    // You can access the button within setInvisible() method
    start.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: yes, that's what i did :) i modified my code in the question to reflect this. thnx 4 ur help :)

Comment: @user3541263 plese don't modify your question. Let us see what you asked and how it is resolved :)

Comment: OK...will remember...thnx for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void myButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.myButton1.Hide();
    }
}
```

InitilizeComponent method:

```
        this.myButton1 = new WindowsFormsApplication4.MyButton();
        this.myButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myButton1_Click);
```